# Is it best practice to modify the production code to be testable / solely for testing purposes?

Tags: java, testing

currently in production code, I have a function as such

```
public void doWork() {
    ... call functionA
    ... call functionB
    ... do other work
}
```

I have to test a case where I need to pause after functionA is called in doWork(). And there is no way for me to pause through testing framework

so I've changed the production to be

```
public void doWork() {
    doWork(new CountdownLatch(0))
}
public void doWork(CountdownLatch latch) {
    ... call functionA with a latch and functionA calls latch.await()
    ... call functionB
    ... do other work
}
```

Now, i can create a test case and test with `doWork(new CountdownLatch(1))`

But in production it will always be calling `doWork()` which in turn calls `doWork(new CountdownLatch(0))`

Is this unnecessary overhead just to be able to make the code test-able? or is this acceptable?

Comment: @BackSlash did you read the whole question? the production code is not testable. it has nothing do with test environment?

Comment: Why do you need to stop? What are you trying to test?

Comment: @Januson a race condition. after funtionA is called I need to modified the resources and expects a certain behavior (test for) when functionB is called

Comment: So, you want to test the code in a way it doesn't run in production, and you want a "best practice" for that?  Best practice would seem to me to be to test the code the same way it runs in production.  Does your production code run with delays like that?  If not, you need to explain better why you need a delay.

Comment: @AndrewHenle completely opposite. i want to test the code the way it runs in production but there is no way to simulate that in a testing framework

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly `functionA` is called (is it a function of the same object or some other object passed is a parameter), but you can mock it so that it calls the actual `functionA` at first and then calls some external `CountDownLatch`. Could you please say, how exactly `functionA` is called?

Comment: @dmitrievanthony cannot mock. it is a final class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modification of your code in order to make it testable is completely valid. Test is just another client of your code and as such provides feedback on the usability of the code.

On the other hand for the feedback to be constructive, test has to abide to some rules. Such as it should test behavior of the code and not its internals.

Now, for the actual testing you have more options.

- Most strait-forward would be to use a test double for its dependencies. You mentioned that the functionA is final and so it cannot be mocked. It can. While not ideal solution both [Mockito 2.+](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What's-new-in-Mockito-2#mock-the-unmockable-opt-in-mocking-of-final-classesmethods) and [PowerMock](http://powermock.github.io/) support mocking of `final classes`.
- Cleaner way would be to listen to your tests. Your tests are telling you that your code has design problems. Maybe you could fix those. You could for example try to separate threading and execution logic so that it can be tested. Or you could introduce an interface to make dependencies mockable.